# Ограничение фпс

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Итак, моя проблема заключается вот в чём. Я создал небольшую игру на Unity и ограничил фпс до 200. При билде игра работает сначала в 200 фпс как положено, но спустя минуту фпс падает до 150. После смерти персонажа и попадания в менюшку так вообще до 75 (Частота обновления монитора тоже 75). V-Sync отключен. С ПК проблема не связана абсолютно (В плане производительности), ибо без ограничений фпс под 2к. По этой причине и ставил ограничение. Собственно, я в замешательстве. Не понимаю из-за чего такая проблема.

Comment: Проблема видимо в коде...

Comment: В коде нет никаких ограничений фпс дополнительных и изменений V-Sync Count. Только основной ограничитель и всё

Comment: А почему обязательно должен быть ограничитель фпс в коде? Всё банально проще: код **кривой**. Поэтому вешает всё что может